# Render a ripple over the whole surface of a Card

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

Is it possible to have a ripple rendered over the whole surface of a `Card`?

`InkWell` with a child `Card` renders the ripple behind the `Card`; `Card` itself doesn't have an `onTap` handler...

So, how to get that ripple?

Comment: My understanding is that InkWell renders its ripple effect on the enclosing Material.

InkWell adds itself to its enclosing material:
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/bf017b7/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_splash.dart#L109

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put the InkWell inside the Card.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple :)

Answer (score -1):

Put this simple code

```
Card(
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {}, 
),
```